# c# - Ajax.BeginForm - 500 Error - Resource cannot found

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to submit my form using Ajax.beginform. I tried everything but i am getting this resource cannot found error.

I have two models - PatientEligibility and PatientDetails. Both contains 10-12 properties respectively.

I have created on viewmodel using those two models and I am trying to use some of the properties in one partial view and submitting that data button click

my view -

```
 @model Portal.Models.EligibilityViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
        $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
</script>
<div class="row margin-top-0">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <h4><b>Patient Eligibility</b></h4>
</div>
</div>

   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitPatientEligibility", "Ophthalmic", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }))
{
<div class="row margin-top-10">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="margin-top-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.PatientEligibility.IsAboveSixty, new { @Name = "cbAgeEligibility", htmlAttributes = new { id = "cbAbvSixty", @class = "form-control", Name = "group1[]" } })
                    The patient is 60 or over
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="margin-top-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.PatientEligibility.IsBelowSixteen, new { @Name = "cbAgeEligibility", htmlAttributes = new { id = "cbUnderSixteen", @class = "form-control", Name = "group1[]" } })
                    The patient is under 16
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="margin-top-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.PatientEligibility.IsBetweenForty, new { @Name = "cbAgeEligibility", htmlAttributes = new { id = "cbAbovenForty", @class = "form-control", Name = "group1[]" } })
                    The patient is 40 or over and is the parent/brother/sister/child of a person who has or has had gloucoma
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="margin-top-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.PatientEligibility.IsStudent, new { @Name = "cbAgeEligibility", htmlAttributes = new { id = "cbStudent", @class = "form-control", Name = "group1[]" } })
                    The patient is full time student aged 16, 17 or 18 at the establishment below.
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="margin-top-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.PatientEligibility.IsPrisoner, new { data_toggle = "collapse", data_target = "#dvseenNotseen", htmlAttributes = new { id = "cbPrisoner", @class = "form-control" } })
                    The patient is prisoner on leave  from the prison detailed below
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="margin-top-10">
        @Html.LabelFor(p => p.PatientBenefit.NINNumber)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PatientBenefit.NINNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" } })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="margin-top-10">
        <label>DATE OF BIRTH</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PatientBenefit.DOB, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off", @id = "datetimepicker1" })
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="row margin-top-10">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-default" name="btnBack">Previous</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-default" name="btnBack">Save Draft</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success fa fa-chevron-right icon-right" name="btnNext" type="submit">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and my model is like this -

```
 public class EligibilityViewModel
{
    public PatientEligibility PatientEligibility { get; set; }

    public PatientBenefit PatientBenefit { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to call this method on submit of Next button -

```
  public class OphthalmicController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitPatientEligibility(EligibilityViewModel model)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

i dont know why but i am getting this 500 error resource cannot found for this method.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the method marked `[HttpPost]`?. But none of this will work anyway - you changing `name` attributes so they have no relationship to your model and therefore will not be bound

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes it is marked as [HttpPost] .. i removed that name attribute now...but  still no luck

Comment: Use you browser tools (the Network tab) to inspect the response which will include the details of the error (and I assume the real code is not `return null;` = that would not make sense)